# What are the units of $U(\mathfrak{sl}_2)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, lie-algebras

Let $U(\mathfrak{sl}_2)$ be the [Universal Enveloping Algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_enveloping_algebra) of $\mathfrak{sl_2}$ over a field $K$, i.e. the (non-commutative) algebra generated by three generators $E,F,H$ subject to the commutator relations

$$[E,F] = H, \quad
[H,E] = 2E,\quad
[H,F] = -2F.$$

What are the units of $U(\mathfrak{sl}_2)$?

In view of the natural inclusion $\iota \colon K \to U(\mathfrak{sl}_2)$ and the projection $\pi \colon U(\mathfrak{sl}_2) \to K$ (sending $E,F,H$ to $0$), it is clear that all units $u$ of $K$ yield units $\iota(u)$ of $U(\mathfrak{sl}_2)$, and all units $v \in U(\mathfrak{sl}_2)$ map to units in $K$ under $\pi$, hence are of the form $v = \iota(\pi(v)) +p(E,F,H)$, where $p$ is a polynomial expression without constant term (this makes use of the [Poicare-Birkhoff-Witt Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9%E2%80%93Birkhoff%E2%80%93Witt_theorem)), and $\iota(\pi(v))$ is the image of a unit in $K$.